# Autorotation And resizing

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, ios-simulator

M developing an application which starts with a login page.
After loggin the user will see a tableview.Selecting a row he will be directed to a web view showing a HTML content.

Till here everything went fine.Now i want to see the webview in a landscape 
mode.I have dismissed the login view.The project template is view based.

Okay one more thing the table view is on the root view controller,after dismissing the login page when I rotate the simulator the webview rotates but it does not resizes.

Upper half of the screen is the webview but the lower half(in landscape mode) is the login page.

How can get rid of this ?

ThankYou All .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the autoresizingMask is set properly for things that are not resizing.  This is easiest in IB where you can set a view to resize both vertically and horizontally.